# It is possible to extend interface and modify parent properties without redeclare all properties?

Tags: typescript

I have interface `IObfuscatorOptions`, which describe package custom options object (for user).

```
export interface IObfuscatorOptions {
    compact?: boolean;
    debugProtection?: boolean;
    debugProtectionInterval?: boolean;
    disableConsoleOutput?: boolean;
    encodeUnicodeLiterals?: boolean;
    reservedNames?: string[];
    rotateUnicodeArray?: boolean;
    selfDefending?: boolean;
    sourceMap?: boolean;
    sourceMapMode?: TSourceMapMode;
    unicodeArray?: boolean;
    unicodeArrayThreshold?: number;
    wrapUnicodeArrayCalls?: boolean;
    [key: string]: any;
}
```

Now i want to create a internal class `Options` with members - all options from `IObfuscatorOptions`. **This class will implements interface `IOptions`.**

I want that interface `IOptions` contains all options from `IObfuscatorOptions`, but without `optional` modifier and with `readonly` modifier.

It is possible to do that without redeclaring all `IObfuscatorOptions` properties like i do now?

```
// bad bad bad
export interface IOptions {
    readonly compact: boolean;
    readonly debugProtection: boolean;
    readonly debugProtectionInterval: boolean;
    readonly disableConsoleOutput: boolean;
    readonly encodeUnicodeLiterals: boolean;
    readonly reservedNames: string[];
    readonly rotateUnicodeArray: boolean;
    readonly selfDefending: boolean;
    readonly sourceMap: boolean;
    readonly sourceMapMode: TSourceMapMode;
    readonly unicodeArray: boolean;
    readonly unicodeArrayThreshold: number;
    readonly wrapUnicodeArrayCalls: boolean;
}
```